# Swift Vapor Filter with field type Array containing a value

Tags: swift, database, vapor

I am trying to create a method where Players can fetch their messages in a game.

The message object has a property `receivers` which is an array of `UUID` containing Player IDs (in case messages are sent to multiple players).

How do I use a `.filter` operation to query items where an array contains an id?

Here is my Message `Model`

```
final class UserMessage:Model, Content {

    static let schema:String = "messages"

    @ID() var id: UUID?

    // sender
    @Field(key: "sender")
    var sender: UUID

    // receivers
    @Field(key: "receivers")
    var receivers: [UUID]

    @Field(key: "title")
    var title: String

    @Field(key: "body")
    var body: String

    @Field(key: "date")
    var date: Date
}
```

And here is the `RouteCollection` method.

```
func readAllMessages(req:Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<[UserMessage]> {
    
    // Needs player ID
    guard let pidString = req.parameters.get("pid"),
          let pid = UUID(uuidString: pidString) else {
        throw Abort(.methodNotAllowed)
    }
    
    // FIXME: - Needs to return ONLY where \.receivers:[UUID] contains pid
    
    return UserMessage.query(on: req.db).all().map { messages in
        
        // Is this a too expensive operation?
        var validMessages = messages.filter({ $0.receiver.contains(pid)})
        
        return validMessages
    }
}
```

I initially tried using the `~~` filter, as described in [Vapor Docs here](https://docs.vapor.codes/4.0/fluent/query/#contains-filter)

But that only works in the opposite direction (Collection on the RHS).

I am also avoiding the creation of multiple relational tables, to reduce the amount of `Content` objects needed by the app. However, if that cannot be accomplished I am also open to a different suggestion/solution.

Comment: It seems to me this is a typical scenario of [One-to-many](https://docs.vapor.codes/4.0/fluent/relations/) relationship. Not sure why you are trying to avoid it.

Comment: I think its a Many-to-many (needs Pivot Table) since the Player can receive many messages and a message can have many 'receivers'. I was trying to avoid having huge queries, or too many models. But perhaps that's inevitable. I thought I'd ask though. You never know when someone may come up with a ninja solution. lol. If this was a HackerRank question, I'm sure someone would figure it out.

Comment: Use a pivot table, it will be far more efficient than looping through all the messages to find the messages for a receiver